# Scala spark: Access value in a struct in an array-typed column? (Or, access member of anonymous struct-typed column)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe that has a column which is an array of structs, like:

```
+-----+-----+------------------+---+----+
|index|state|entries           |0  |1   |
+-----+-----+------------------+---+----+
|0    |KY   |[[A, 45]]         |45 |null|
|1    |OR   |[[A, 30], [B, 10]]|30 |10  |
+-----+-----+------------------+---+----+
```

where "Entries" are structs with two fields, "name" and "number". I want to be able to grab one of those inner values at a particular index.

One way I could do this is:

```
df.withColumn(col("entries").getItem(0), "dumbName").select("dumbName.name")
```

I want to be able to do this with anonymous columns, though, so it would look more like

`col("entries").getItem(0).someMagicFunction("name")`

Comment: So what is the issue here? Its not clear what do you want to do.

Comment: I was trying to find a syntax that would work similarly to the "someMagicFunction" implementation, without requiring adding a named column to the dataframe. If you check the approved answer, it gives an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getItem` works as *magic function*:

```scala
df.select(col("entries").getItem(0).getItem("Name")).show()
```

prints

```
+---------------+
|entries[0].Name|
+---------------+
|              A|
|              A|
+---------------+
```

It is also possible to use `element_at` from the [functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) object  (available since 2.4.0):

```scala
df.select(element_at('entries, 1).getItem("Name")).show()
```

prints

```
+---------------------------+
|element_at(entries, 1).Name|
+---------------------------+
|                          A|
|                          A|
+---------------------------+
```

For earlier Spark versions it would be possible to use SQL:

```scala
df.createOrReplaceGlobalTempView("df")
spark.sql("select entries[0].name from global_temp.df").show()
```